# SSPI client requires less iterations than GSSAPI server

Tags: security, kerberos, windows-authentication, gssapi, sspi

I'm using [nsspi](https://github.com/antiduh/nsspi) to call SSPI APIs from a C# application for the client side. I'm using cyrus sasl with a MIT Kerberos GSSAPI implementation on the server side.

The two protocols seem to talk to each other but the server seems to require **more challenges** to the client than the client is willing to perform.

Here's a client debug log:

```
- Creating client context
- CONTINUE_NEEDED after calling InitializeSecurityContext, sending clientToken to the server
- received new server challenge
- OK after calling InitializeSecurityContext, out clientToken is null.
- no data to send to the server, sending NULL data
- received new server challenge
- NSspi.SSPIException: Failed to invoke InitializeSecurityContext for a client. Error Code = '0x80090301' - "The handle provided to the API was invalid.".
```

here's a server debug log:

```
- received client packet
- SASL start with GSSAPI
- GSSAPI server step 1
- received CONTINUE
- sending challenge to client
- received client packet with NULL data
- GSSAPI server step 2
- sending challenge to client
- client ended unexpectedly
```

The code is rather lengthy so I cannot paste it here entirely. The issue seems to be in the number of authentication rounds involved: the client is satisfied after just one round, the server seems to require more rounds but the client has no data to pass to it.

I'm using [the same flags as the nsspi client demo](https://github.com/antiduh/nsspi/blob/master/TestClient/ClientForm.cs#L50) for context creation.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Though, a bit late. This sounds odd. Which SASL mech did you use? GSSAPI? Are you certain that your C# is RFC-compliant? Share the context flags on the client side.